# tomcat server ignores to load persistence.xml on startup (HIbernate OGM, Mongodb, Spring boot)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, tomcat8, hibernate-ogm

I have an spring boot application running fine with in my eclipse which is configured with hibernate ogm and mongodb.

when i tried to deploy this project war file in external tomcat it is showing the following error.

> 26-Jul-2018 18:28:16.155 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.dmp.config.DBConfigContextListener]
>    org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000071: Unable to start datastore provider
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.start(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:121)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.startService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:339)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:245)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectInitiator.java:52)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectInitiator.java:36)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator$OgmDialectFactory.(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:44)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:31)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:25)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:50)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmJdbcServicesInitiator$OgmJdbcServicesImpl.configure(OgmJdbcServicesInitiator.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:57)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>       at com.dmp.config.DBConfigContextListener.contextInitialized(DBConfigContextListener.java:15)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001214: Unable to connect to MongoDB instance: Command failed with error 13: 'there are no users authenticated' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "there are no users authenticated", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.extractDatabase(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:186)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.start(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:116)
>       ... 49 more
>   Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'there are no users authenticated' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "there are no users authenticated", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }
>       at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:164)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:98)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:441)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:80)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:189)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:264)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:126)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:226)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:217)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:120)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation$1.call(ListCollectionsOperation.java:178)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation$1.call(ListCollectionsOperation.java:173)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:471)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation.execute(ListCollectionsOperation.java:173)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation.execute(ListCollectionsOperation.java:81)
>       at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:826)
>       at com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:130)
>       at com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:77)
>       at com.mongodb.MappingIterable.iterator(MappingIterable.java:40)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.extractDatabase(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:172)
>       ... 50 more

26-Jul-2018 18:28:16.158 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
26-Jul-2018 18:28:16.166 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.dmp.config.DBConfigContextListener]
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dmp.config.DBConfigContextListener.contextDestroyed(DBConfigContextListener.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4798)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5437)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

my **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="dmp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="dmp_test" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port" value="27017" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/tmp/.hibernate_ogm_demo_luceneindexes"/> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>com.dmp</groupId>
<artifactId>dmp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>dmp</name>
<description>Top RTB DMP Process</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.ogm/hibernate-ogm-bom -->
<!-- <dependencyManagement> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId> 
    <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId> <version>5.3.1.Final</version> 
    <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> </dependency> </dependencies> </dependencyManagement> -->


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- maxmind geo ip dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoip-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- Add the Narayana Transactions Manager an implementation would be provided 
        in a Java EE container, but this works nicely in Java SE as well -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId> <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId> 
        <version>5.8.1.Final</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ <scope>test</scope> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts.arjunacore</groupId> <artifactId>arjuna</artifactId> 
        <version>4.17.4.Final</version> </dependency> -->       <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.scientiamobile.wurfl</groupId>
        <artifactId>wurfl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
        <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.4.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.scientiamobile.wurfl</id>
        <name>com.scientiamobile.wurfl</name>
        <url>https://maven.scientiamobile.com/repository/wurfl-onsite/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>dmp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    -Xdebug
                    -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9898
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**DBConfigContextListner.java**

```
public class DBConfigContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dmp");
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    emf.close();
}

public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    if (emf == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Context is not initialized yet.");
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

}

**SpringTestApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class SpringTestApplication {

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> listenerRegistrationBean() {
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> bean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
    bean.setListener(new DBConfigContextListener());
    return bean;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringTestApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

**application.properties**

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Also tell me that the above property in application.properties is mandatory or not.

as of my understanding the provider is not loading at server startup. but i dont know how to make it load manually.

Kindly help to fix this issue if anyone knows how to solve.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jeevitha T

Comment: What exception has been thrown by "Provider named org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory:"?

Comment: Error: 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.dmp.config.DBConfigContextListener]
 org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000071: Unable to start datastore provider

i think persistent unit is not recognised by the tomcat server. so that the connection to the data base is not established. can you pls tell me how to fix this.

Comment: @Davide I will also update my question with corresponding pom file and entity manager configuration file. pls have a look at it and tell me is there any changes has to be done.